# Access Google Cloud SQL directly or via pub sub queues?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-sql

Scenario:

We have two options:

Option 1. An Web Service on Premises (organisation), will push the messages on Google Cloud Pub Sub Queues via VPN tunnel. Cloud function listening to pub sub queues, picks the messages and update the cloud SQL database.

Option 2. A Web Service on Premises (organisation) directly write into the cloud SQL database.

Architecture wise which option is the best? Option 1 or Option 2

Can anybody provide some suggestions?

Comment: I don't quite get what exactly you are trying to achieve here but if the only thing you want to do with this 'messages' is to write them to a Cloud SQL DB I don't see a point in using two more steps with writing to Cloud Pub/Sub and triggering a Cloud Function to write them to DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment I don't see a point in using two more steps just to write data in CloudSQL DB. If all you want to do is to store data to DB, option 2 is the most simple and fast way to do so. There is no need to complicate things with writing messages to Cloud Pub/Sub and triggering a Cloud Function to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pub/Sub if the number of connections will be higher than CloudSQL can handle. If you have 2000 smart toilets reporting data, use pub/sub. If you have 5 boxes pushing messages, go with CloudSQL.